# What is the significance of this `java` command?

Tags: java, linux

I have below command in one of my legacy script and I am struggling to understand it properly. Can anybody help me here?

```
java -cp //applications/programs/myjar.jar:applications/programs/ojdbc14.zip mypkg.MyClass //application
```

Is it copying 2 files to "applications" and then executing it with "java"?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the manual page http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/

-cp means class path and not copy

Answer (score 1):

`man java` explains:

> `-classpath classpath`
>   `-cp classpath`
>
> Specifies a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files.  Class path entries are separated by colons (`:`). Specifying `-classpath` or `-cp` overrides any setting of the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.
>
> If `-classpath` and `-cp` are not used and `CLASSPATH` is not set, the user class path consists of the current directory (`.`).